# Query and import targeted data in seperate Google Spreadsheets

Tags: google-sheets

I'm trying to use Google Spreadsheets in conjunction with a Google form to 'collect' data, use the collected data to locate associated data in a source spreadsheet, and then import that targeted data into a separate target spreadsheet. I've done some research in Google Groups and 'think' I have the basic function, but I'm missing the 'if/then' portion and the syntax is off.

[image]

**RED** cell in 'target' will be used to locate the appropriate row in 'source'.

**Green** cell in 'target' will be used to locate the appropriate column in 'source'.

**What I have so far...**
=QUERY(importRange("[key]", "Sheet1!A1:C5"), `"select Col1, Col2, Col3 where Col2='data1'", 1)`

The `"select Col1, Col2, Col3 where Col2='data1'", 1)` portion of the function is the part I'm stuck on.

**First,** I want to locate a row in the source spreadsheet based on cell data in the target spreadsheet. **For example**, `where Col2='B2'", 1)`

**Second,** I want to pull specific data from the source spreadsheet based on a 'if statement' 
**For example,** if col3=2nd then copy col4, col5 if col3=3rd then copy col6, col7. **I know this section is completely off.

Any suggestion? 
Thanks everyone!

Todd

High School Teacher @ Grossmont High School

Comment: Yes, why?  And why [gas] tag either?

Comment: pnuts, I added the excel tag because it was 'recommended' by the system and many of the posts about spreadsheets use both (excel and google spreadsheets). If that is poor etiquette, I will discontinue.
Serge insas, I added the GAS tag because I believe this can be accomplished using GAS 'if' a function won't work. I see a lot of the more involved requests tag both the drive app and GAS.

Answer (score 0):

`=VLOOKUP($B2,Sheet2!$A$1:$G$7,MATCH("Teacher"&LEFT($C2,1),Sheet2!$A1:$G1,0)+COLUMN()-4,0)` in D2 and copied into E2 of Target sheet seems to work in both Excel and Google Doc spreadsheet, though it is not a script.

Comment: pnuts, "thank you", this function is close, but not there yet. 1st it needs to pull the teacher name and the teacher email address from the source. How do I modify it to include '2 columns' instead of one?

2nd it needs to also work with a 'separate' spreadsheet document, not just sheet2 within the document. How to I modify it so it also looks for the document key & sheet name?

Thank you very much pnuts!

Comment: Sorry, I hit enter instead of "shift enter". I'm working on it now.

Comment: Pnuts, it is going to be in a separate workbook. What do you suggest?